# Bootstrap - What is wrong with this code?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

Using bootstrap classes, I want that every element has a width of 100% by Desktop and tablet view but 50% by Mobile view.
But I don't understand why it doesn't work as it should.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="panel">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
         some text
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <span class="text">Accordion with image and text</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.panel {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  align-items: center;

  div {
    outline: 1px solid red;
  }

}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,the  **-xs-**  infix was removed from **Bootstrap 4** ,so the classes are simply **col-1, col-2,col-3, col-12**.

As you have mention that you want every element has a width of 100% by Desktop and tablet view but 50% by Mobile view.

You should use the below code.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-6">
       some text
  </div>
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-6">
       Accordion with image and text
  </div>
</div>
```